# Deserialize Firebase dataSnapshot to Kotlin data class

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have some issue. I am using Firebase Realtime Database and want to deserialize dataSnapshot from `onDataChange` to Kotlin data class (which I created from JSON of Firebase Realtime Database).

I have recyclerview in project and want to pass data to adapter by my data class (e.g. Order) but I get response with DataSnapshot type.

Here is my code:

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val list = mutableListOf<Order>()
                list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Order::class.java)!!)
                println(list)
                ordersAdapter.setDataToAdapter(list)
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("data", "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
            }
        })
```

The problem is i'm getting exception: `Class Order does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.`

Here is my data class:

```
data class Order(
 @SerializedName("additional_phone")
    val additionalPhone: Int = 0,
    val address: String = "",
    @SerializedName("client_id")
    val clientId: Int = 0,
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    val createdAt: String = "",
    val delivery: Delivery?,
    val id: Int = 0,
    val total: Double = 0.0,
    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    val updatedAt: String = "",
    @SerializedName("vendor_id")
    val vendorId: Int = 0
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a secondary constructor with no arguments, I think one of the snapshot data is empty and data class is using only primary constructor so having a secondary constructor with empty values will help, for e.g.:

```
    {
       constructor() : this(0, "",0, 
                     "", null, 0, 0.0, "",0 )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I created secondary constructor and I understood that I can make only this: `val delivery: Delivery? = null` without declaring secondary constructor.